# MySQL replication works about a day

Tags: mysql, replication

Replication Master - Slave.

Master local machine Win Server 2008 R2 with OpenServer (PHP 7.1, MySQL 5.7).

Slave in the cloud Debian 9 (PHP 7.1, Percona Server 5.7).

Master conf:

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 1
log_bin = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\logs\\%mysql_driver%_bin.log"
binlog_do_db = car
sync_binlog = 0
binlog-format = mixed
```

Slave conf:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2
replicate-do-table=car.tovar
replicate-do-table=car.goods
log-bin= "MySQL-5.7-x64_bin"
.....
```

screen start replication
[image]

After about a day, when replication is no longer working
[image]

I check it is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM goods ORDER BY `update` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I see that column `update` is not updated.

Every day it repeats itself.

What could be the problem? Thank

Comment: I think `UPDATE` is a reserved keyword of mysql

Comment: it is unlikely.... replication worked normally, but through certain time constantly stops without mistakes

Comment: _it is unlikely_ Take alook at [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-reserved-words.html, but I have no mistakes